# Запятая перед союзом и: "и в случае ..."

Tags: пунктуация

Теперь смотрю на это по-другому(,) и в случае, если вижу, что была не права, признаю свои ошибки.

Нужна ли запятая перед союзом "и"? Почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы добавил, что в этом предложении не нужна запятая и перед "если", так как здесь налицо составной подчинительный союз "в случае если". Я бы расставил здесь запятые так:  "Теперь смотрю на это по-другому и, в случае если вижу, что была не права, признаю свои ошибки".

Answer (score 1):

Запятая перед союзом И не нужна, так как он соединяет однородные сказуемые СМОТРЮ и ПРИЗНАЮ. Ср. : Теперь смотрю на это по-другому и в случае [моей неправоты]... признаю свои ошибки.